# Spring Boot - How to use JWT token without using username or password?

Tags: java, spring-boot, backend

I have a system where there is no login process, no username and no password - imagine this like a Tinder or Whatsapp registration process where the main "username" is a phone number, it is a unique identifier. The problem is with spring's security UserDetails class that overrides a method loadUserByUsername. What username? I dont have it. I need this class to use jwt tokens but i cant use it because of the username method....

Comment: as you already said. just use the phone number as user name then.

Comment: 1) why would i have a code that says `loadUserByUsername` and then pass a phoneNumber as the parameter...? That would confuse everyone. 2) it requires me to pass in the password as the 2nd parameter. I dont have a password at all and it is a required field...

Comment: Have you managed to generate JWT without password?